# Intercepting WinAPI calls and modifying return values

Tags: c++, winapi

I've seen applications such as [RunAsDate](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html) can modify system functions, and just for certain software so that when they run, and call OS methods, those calls return altered values.

> RunAsDate intercepts the kernel API calls that returns the current
>   date and time (GetSystemTime, GetLocalTime, GetSystemTimeAsFileTime),
>   and replaces the current date/time with the date/time that you
>   specify.

Now I'd love to do the same, only that I'd wish I could alter `GetMonitorInfo`.
All good except I have no idea where to start. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Bonus points if no antivirus detects this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The common solution for this is [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) . Obviously, any good anti-virus program will *detect* it, but you've got a reasonable chance that it will tolerate Detours since it comes from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

You can install a **hook** for that particular function. Here's a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how to do so.

Comment: That's limited to a very specific set of functions, not including `GetMonitorInfo`.